# Слитно или раздельно пишется слово "слабозащищенный"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Слитно или раздельно пишется слово *слабозащищенных* в предложении:

*Важной задачей является адресная социальная поддержка слабо защищенных слоев населения*?

Answer (score 3):

Здесь ***слабозащищенный*** является термином и пишется слитно, например:Специфика трудоустройства **слабозащищённых** категорий

https://studopedia.ru/5_50648_spetsifika-trudoustroystva-slabozashchishchennih-kategoriy.html

Также: Что же касается самих Т-26, то эти на первый взгляд устаревшие, **слабозащищенные,** уязвимые машины были незаменимы в разведке и десантах. [Олег Тарасов. Возвращение в 42-й // «Техника - молодежи», 1991]